# In North Carolina, should I be paid anything if I show up to work and am sent home right away?

Tags: salary, united-states

Specifically the rules for this question for working in the state of NC. Say I show up to work and my employer says they don't need me and send me home, should I be getting paid for the hours I was scheduled?

Comment: All I can comment on is, in my last job, I got 2 hours of "show up pay" if I showed up, but they ended up not needing me.  Otherwise I wasn't paid for the time I was supposed to work.  But I'd guess no, why should they pay you if you don't do the work?

Comment: @New-To-IT Well, you did come all the way to the job site, and it's a balance of power situation (the company has all the power).

Comment: @New-To-IT It's a balance against the fact that employers don't have to pay salaried exempt employees for overtime hours, to prevent abuse. If salaried exempt employees show up "ready, willing, and able" to work the employer generally has to pay them their salary even if they don't do any work (e.g. because the building is closed or there's nothing to do). If the employer doesn't want to pay for un-worked hours, they can classify the employees as hourly (but then they have to pay for *every* hour worked).

Answer (score 5):

"An employer is not required to pay a minimum number of hours to its hourly paid employees or to its non-exempt salary employees including if they are called back in. An employer only has to pay its hourly employees and non-exempt salary employees for the actual hours worked regardless of how long or how few the time is."

Source: http://www.nclabor.com/wh/fact%20sheets/minhours.htm

Comment: Unless you're a foreign worker on an H class visa - in which case you have to be paid no less than the amount specified on your LCA, even if the company has no work for you to do...

Comment: @brhans and that sounds so FAlR

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton That's what happens when both federal and state laws deal in the same arena.

Comment: Well - its is fair because the H-Visa holder is not allowed to get alternative employment to fill the gap, and the employer had to assert that they couldn't find a local to fill the position and that they would be prepared to pay that salary/wage/whatever in order to get the H-visa issued.